# ¿Cómo cuento cuantas veces está en muestra una unidad?

Tags: r

R
Tengo un archivo con ID, año y mes. Quiero saber cuantos meses ha estado la unidad en muestra dentro del periodo de los 11 años. Por ejemplo, tal vez la unidad X me contestó en los meses 01 y 02 del año 2009, meses 03, 04, 05 del año 2011 y mes 12 del año 2015. Pues quiero una variable de recuento que me diga "la unidad X ha estado 6 meses en muestra".
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es una tabla de frecuencias, es decir, las veces que aparece cada `ID` en el `data.frame` lo más sencillo es usar `table()`, por ejemplo:

```
table(df$ID)
```

Ahora, si buscas contar valor únicos, con R base podrías hacer algo así:

```
aggregate(paste(mes, año) ~ ID, data = df, FUN=function(x){length(unique(x))})
```

Es decir, agrupamos por `ID` y contamos ocurrencias únicas de `mes` y `año`

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, te muestro una usando tidyverse:

```
# creo dataframe de prueba
ID<-c(rep(1:3,10), rep(4:6,2))
mes<-rep(1:12, 3)
anho<-rep(c(2019,2020,2021),each=3)

df<-data.frame(ID,mes,anho)

library(tidyverse)
# tabla con ID, mes, año y además un columna con el recuento
df %>% group_by (ID) %>% mutate(recuento=length(unique(paste0(mes,anho))))

# tabla con ID y recuento solamente
df %>% group_by (ID) %>% summarise(recuento=length(unique(paste0(mes,anho))))
```